# Where did my TFS history go?

Tags: tfs

I just went to do a merge into our dev integration branch and found that the child branch no longer seems to have a relationship with it's parent (dev). So I went to the parent branch (dev) and viewed history and it says there is none! There should definitely be history - I've merged there several times.

[image]

Anyone know what to do with this? Short of restoring a DB backup and losing everything checked in since the backup was taken I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I was in a group that had access denied to the given branch and when I removed myself from that group I could then see the history again.